# Angular 2 styles not showing as I want in dev-tools

Tags: css, typescript, sass, angular

I'm working on an angular 2 project and got stuck on this issue:

1. I use sass to compile my style to compressed css:
   [image]
2. Then I get the css-file in my component:
   [image]
3. The style-code works. BUT when I check dev-tools it looks like this:
   [image] (notice the "`<style>...</style>`" in the end)
4. Now, my problem is that I want the styles to be shown like this:
   [image]

Anyone that knows how I can fix this?

Comment: you can put styles in your `index.html` file, if that is an option. BTW what is wrong with `<style>..</style>` ?

Comment: @A_Singh Yeah, I've also thought about putting it inside of index.html as an option but I want the style to be more dynamic and not static as it would be if I put them in index.html... About the style text, I just don't like how is it displayed. I've never seen any good code shown this way and it just looks unprofessional :/

Comment: AFAI can think, it's there for a reason, to cater to only a particular component, not meant for others. if you want this to look good you can inject them in head of `index.html` in your components `constructor` manually and then remove in `ngOnDestroy()` lifecycle hook. unprofessional ? I can't tell, i'm not very professional

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Angular CLI, you can add the --extract-css true flag to the CLI command, like so,

```
$ ng s -o --extract-css true
```

In this way, you get a link to the CSS line so you can drill into it.

[image]